# Genymotion - Get Address from Longitude und Latitude

Tags: android, google-geocoder, genymotion

I use this code, to get my current address:

```
public String getAdressFromLongLat(double lati, double longi) {
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext,Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lati, longi, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    if(addresses==null || addresses.size()<=0) {
        return null;
    }
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    return address + "/;/" + city;
}
```

But it returns everytime null. I have no real device, so I test in a genymotion emulator. Is this the problem? Or is something wrong with the code?

-> I used the debugger to find the problem:
addresses is not null, but the size is 0, why? :(

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that Genymotion doesn't support address lookup. From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html):

> Note: Address lookup requires a backend service that is not included
>   in the core Android framework. If this backend service is not
>   available, Geocoder.getFromLocation() returns an empty list. The
>   helper method isPresent(), available in API level 9 and later, checks
>   to see if the backend service is available.

Try calling [Geocoder.isPresent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent%28%29) to be sure.